# Error: Argument appears to not be a ReactComponent. Keys: focus,blur,scrollTo

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

All:

[image]

When i click the submit-button, then console the error

Comment: can you add minimum re-producible code to help us out here? Will need to check what happens when button is clicked.

Comment: You should post your component code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.